# Negative Lookbehind Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code which attempts to match all strings like "*SOMESTRING" (which can include numeric values), but *not* "*SOMESTRING*". For this I am using a negative lookahead as follows;`*SEX` and `*AN01ZORA` *should* match, `\*PCCL\*` should *not* match.

```
string s = "   if 'L,....' MDC = '13' Then " +
           "  if 'B,960.' SEX NOT = '2' AND *SEX NOT = '3' Then " +
           " DRG = 960Z (UNGROUPABLE) " +
           "    GoTo MDC FldErr " +
           "Else if 'B,N01.' SRG IN TABLE(*AN01ZORA) Then " +
           "  if '.,N01.' *PCCL* > 2 Then ";
Regex rr = new Regex(@"(?i)(?!\*\w+\*)\*\w+");
MatchCollection mc = rr.Matches(s);
foreach (Match m in mc)
    m.ToString().Dump();
```

> Output: 
>   *SEX
>   *AN01ZORA

This seems to produce the correct output, but feels nasty and not correct. Is this right and what could I do to make the `Regex` better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is overly complicated, I must admit. The negative lookahead is going to do a lot of work to identify all the negative cases before even looking for (nearly) positive matches.

I think the trick you are missing is [the word-boundary anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordBoundary). Consider the following regex:

```
\*\w+\b
```

This looks for an asterisk, followed by characters, and then a (zero length) word-boundary. Now, both `*SOME*` and `*SOME` match that, since the `\b` happens before the asterisk. The negative lookahead would be useful after the word-boundary. Consider the following:

```
\*\w+\b(?!\*)
```

Look for `*SOME` where the `SOME` is a complete word not followed by an asterisk.

Here's [a little demonstration](http://regex101.com/r/eM7dI2) ....

Edit: Note, there is no reason to add the case-insensitive switch (`(?i)`) because your regular expression has no specific case-based characters.